# Name space pollution from indirectly included module

Tags: perl

Consider the following script `p.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use AA;

BB::bfunc();
```

where the file `AA.pm` is:

```
package AA;

use BB;
1;
```

and the file `BB.pm` is:

```
package BB;

sub bfunc {
    print "Running bfunc..\n";
}
1;
```

Running `p.pl` gives output (with no warnings or errors):

```
Running bfunc..
```

**Q:** Why is it possible to call `BB::bfunc()` from `p.pl` even though there is no `use BB;` in `p.pl`? Isn't this odd behavior? Or are there situation where this could be useful?

(To me, it seems like this behavior only presents an information leak to another package and violates the data hiding principle.. Leading to programs that are difficult to maintain.. )

Comment: Well, you are explicitly referring to another namespace when running it as `BB::bfunc()`. It's not like it's polluted your existing namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not polluting a namespace, because the function within `BB` isn't being 'imported' into your existing namespace.

They are separate, and may be referenced autonomously.

If you're making a module, then usually you'll define via `Exporter` two lists:

`@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`.

The former is the list of things that *should* be imported when you `use` the package.  The latter is the things that you can explicity import via:

```
use MyPackage qw ( some_func );
```

You can also define `package` variables in your local namespace via `our` and reference them via `$main`.

```
 our $fish = "haddock";
 print $main::fish;
```

When you do this, you're explicitly referencing the `main` namespace. When you `use` a module, then you cause `perl` to go and look for it, and include it in your `%INC`. I then 'knows about' that namespace - because it must in order for the dependencies to resolve.

But this isn't namespace pollution, because it doesn't include anything in your namespace until your ask.

This might make a bit more sense if you have multiple packages within the same program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package CC;

our $package_var = "Blong";

sub do_something {
   print $package_var,"\n"; 
}

package main;

use Data::Dumper;
our $package_var = "flonk";
print Dumper $package_var;
print Dumper $CC::package_var;
```

Each `package` is it's own namespace, but you can 'poke' things in another. `perl` will also let you do this with object - poking at the innards of instantiated objects or indeed "patch" them.

That's quite powerful, but I'd generally suggest Really Bad Style.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification. Then it seems this feature has its pros and cons. Maybe the developers of Perl decided that it would not be too harmful to have it, and since it would give some benefits in special cases, they decided to keep it?

Comment: More likely it's because it's always been that way, and changing it might break a lot of things :)

Comment: To what does "if" refer in the above comments?

Comment: Tyop fi it's the thing I think you're referring to.

Answer (score 3):

While it's good practice to `use` or `require` every dependency that you are planning to access (tried to avoid *use* here), you don't have to do that.

As long as you use full package names, that is fine. The important part is that Perl knows about the namespaces. If it does not, it will fail.

When you `use` something, that is equivalent to:

```
BEGIN {
  require Foo::Bar;
  Foo::Bar->import();
}
```

The `require` will take the `Foo::Bar` and convert it to a path according to the operating system's conventions. On Linux, it will try to find `Foo/Bar.pm` somewhere inside `@INC`. It will then load that file and make a note in `%INC` that it loaded the file.

Now Perl knows about that namespace. In case of the `use` it might `import` something into your own namespace. But it will always be available from everywhere after that as long as you use the full name. Just the same, stuff that you have in your main `script.pl` would be available inside of packages by saying `main::frobnicate()`. (Please don't do that!)

It's also not uncommon to bundle several namespaces/packages in one `.pm` module file. There are quite a few big names on CPAN that do it, like [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

If you do that, and don't import anything, the only way to get to the stuff under the different namespaces is by using the full name.

As you can see, this is not polluting at all.

Comment: This feels a bit like rambling, I might clean it up later, but right now I have to run.

Comment: But I wonder, when would it be useful to access the name in another namespace without explicitly including the module with a `use`? Wouldn't this just lead to confusion for a maintainer? Then he suddenly sees a call to function in another namespace that he did not explicitly include. What if maintainer of the `AA` package suddenly decides that he would no longer include namespace `BB`, then the script `p.pl` would break down, and so on..

Comment: Well it would break. True. That's why you should have a test suite. And also why you should include the modules you use. Just because you can do it this way, which could be considered bad style or sloppy doesn't mean you have to do it. I just explained why it works.

Comment: Perl lets you do a bunch of things that are a bad idea in practice. It's _generally_ bad form to reference 'included' stuff based on dependency chaining, especially of modules you don't make use of.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you @sob. Then if course there is also stuff like Modern::Perl or even Moose that load things like strict and warnings into your current namespace.

Comment: Yes. If you're doing anything serious with OO, then using the default implementation is just going to cause you pain. If all you want is a 'super `hash`' then it works well enough. `

Comment: I don't get that comment.

Comment: Er. That if you're doing anything serious that requires e.g. encapsulation techniques like OO, that you should ensure that people _can't_ do nasty things by e.g. using `Moose`. If it's just your code that you're using an object for convenience, then I'd call it less of an issue.

Comment: Re "when would it be useful to access the name in another namespace without explicitly including the module with a use?" 1) When it's documented that loading one module loads a slew of related modules. But primarily, 2) `$o->method` calls `method` is some unknown/arbitrary/variable package. As the user of the object, you should assume the module defining is already loaded. The creator of the object is the one that needs to worry about loading the module.